# Expected norm-squared of one random vector projected onto others, all iid

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion, random-matrices, geometric-probability

For $k\leq n$, $x_1,\dots,x_k \in \mathbb{C}^n$ are independent identically distributed random vectors almost surely unit norm and with span dimension $k$. Call $X=[x_2,\dots,x_k]$. I am studying $\mathbb{E}[\| X(X^\dagger X)^{-1} X^\dagger x_1 \|^2]$ but the inverse is making this challenging. Is there a series expansion in terms of $X$, or another approach to this quantity?

Comment: Do you mean $X^T$ or do you mean to take some kind of pseudo inverse?

Comment: If $X^\dagger$ denotes the transpose of $X$, then $X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T$ is the projection onto the range of $X$.

Comment: $X^\dagger$ is the Hermitian conjugate which is the operation necessary to make that form the complex orthogonal projection